# /users/{id}/tags - broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, api

<strike>looks like touching the id parameter description broke the internet.</strike>

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/242897/tags

should/was working

**6/1/2010 -1:11AM - working**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.